# Getting AvroTypeException when try parse nullable fields

Tags: java, json, parsing, avro

I'm getting my avro schema from Kafka Schema Registry API calling `/subjects/{subject}/versions/latest` and there is one field of `"type":["null","string"]`

I create a new JsonDecoder and DatumReader with this schema:

```
JsonDecoder jsonDecoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, body);
DatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
```

The variable `body` has an jsonString with all fields in the schema, inclusive the optional one...

But, when I call `reader.read(null, jsonDecoder);` I got a `AvroTypeException` with the message: `org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected start-union. Got END_OBJECT`

The same occurs if the `body` doesn't have that field...

Is there some configuration that I'm missig?

The Schema:

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"evolution",
    "namespace":"com.landoop",
    "doc":"This is a sample Avro schema to get you started. Please edit",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"field1",
            "type":"string"
        },{
            "name":"field2",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The body variable:

```
{
    "field1":"value1"
}
```

or

```
{
    "field1":"value1",
    "field2":"value2"
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post the full schema and full `body` data?

Comment: If you get the Java dependency for the `CachedSchemaRegistryClient`, then it has methods to get the Avro `Schema` class for you. You then don't need to manually download and parse the AVSC json body

Answer (score 2):

For the example body that looks like this:

```
{"field1":"value1"}
```

The Java JSON decoder doesn't currently handle situations where a field is missing (even if it has a default value). Since the JAVA JSON encoder always write out the field, the decoder always expects the field to be there.

For the second example that looks like this:

```
{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"}
```

This is not valid JSON encoded Avro data. I'm guessing this is a data structure that was created by some means other than the Avro encoder because the Avro encoder would have created this:

```
{"field1":"value1", "field2": {"string": "value2"}}
```

The specification describes how JSON encoding works in the case of unions and if the value is non-null then it will encode the type information: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#json_encoding